# Can I use "WhatsApp" as a verb in a sentence, and if so what will be the appropriate preposition with it?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Is the sentence "You can WhatsApp me at +91*******" correct and can I use "WhatsApp" as a verb here. I'm confused between the prepositions "WhatsApp me at" and "WhatsApp me on". Can both of them be used interchangeably or is one preferable?

Comment: I think Whatsapp works much the same as SMS text messages or voice calls (users are primarily identified by ***telephone number***), so I suppose the default preposition would be the same as *Call / Message me [**preposition**] #####*. I think we'd mostly use ***on*** there rather than ***at*** - probably because it's primarily a ***communication channel*** rather than an ***address*** *(Write to me **at** my address, Call me **on** my number)*.

Comment: **WhatsApp me at** sounds perfectly natural.

Comment: Google claims an estimated 1.3M hits for **"Whatsapp me at"**, compared to **over 3.2M** hits for **"Whatsapp me on"**

Comment: ...compare that to an estimated 36M hits for **"email me at"**, compared to **under 14M** for **"email me on"**. Both are perfectly "valid", but it's obvious which is more ***likely*** for each of these two contexts and prepositions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, does "WhatsApp at" sound natural to a native speaker

Comment: @Sunaina: Jeffrey obviously thinks so. I gave my preference (for ***on***) in my first comment *and explained why* (and I later confirmed through Google that *most* people apparently favour that version). But there are still ***millions*** of instances of "Whatsapp [someone] **at**", so if you like that version better, you won't be alone!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call on vs Call at vs Call up (at).](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/111491/call-on-vs-call-at-vs-call-up-at) Also [Is it “call us at 181” or “call us on 181”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/284282/is-it-call-us-at-181-or-call-us-on-181)

Comment: I had an answer going but the question just got closed. Yes, as Calvin says ["Verbing weirds language"](https://i.imgur.com/OdZpx.jpg) but it is a common thing to do and using "WhatsApp" as a verb will be clearly understood by any native speaker. In the US I would **never** use "on" for a phone number or any other type of addressing system, only "at," but this is different elsewhere.

Comment: @randomhead so "WhatsApp at" or "WhatsApp on" also depends on native speaker themselves. Do all Americans use "WhatsApp at"/"call at" or is it limited to certain regions?

Comment: I have lived in a couple different parts of the US and have never head "call me on."

Comment: Per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=call+me+on+this+number%2Ccall+me+at+this+number&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3), Brits favour *Call me **on** this number.* But per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=call+me+on+this+number%2Ccall+me+at+this+number&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3), Americans prefer ***at*** there.